# How to expose base class while keeping derived ones internal

Tags: c#, interface, internal

Hello i have the following problem:

I have a struct

```
public struct Cell
{
   public Node Value;
   public static implicit Cell(Node value)=>new Cell(value); //can't since node less accesible then cell
}
```

This struct `Cell` contains a property of type `Node` which is an abstract base class and currently is `internal` with all its derived classes.What i need is to somehow make the `Cell` struct accesible for other developers so that they can extract the value of the `Node` without knowing the `Node` derived class.

```
        internal abstract  class Node{
                internal class ANode:Node{
                    public byte[] internalValue;
                }
                internal class BNode:Node{
                    public int internalValue;
                }
         }
```

How can i achieve this? The `cell` is exposed to outside and so should the abstract base class `Node`.The user should be able to implicit cast from `Node` to `Cell`.

**Current approach**
What i have tried so far is define an interface `IRaw` for `Node` that extracts the content from the `Node` derived classes.The explicit implementation is a virtual method ,overloaded in the derived classes.

```
    interface IRaw{
       byte[] GetRaw();
    }

    internal abstract class Node:IRaw
    {
      byte[] IRaw.GetRaw()=>this.GetRaw();
      protected virtual byte[] GetRaw(){ ....}
    }

    internal class ANode:Node
    {
      protected override byte[] GetRaw()
      {
        .....
      }
    }
```

The problem in the above approach is  that i can not pass the `IRaw` as argument in the `Cell` constructor with the error code:
`user defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed`.

```
 public struct Cell
        {
           public IRaw Value;
           public static implicit Cell(IRaw value)=>new Cell(value);
        }
```

Any suggestions ?I practically need a "Bridge" between the `Cell` which is public and the contents of `Node` which are internal.

Comment: How they can extract the value of the `Node` without knowing the `Node` derived class?

Comment: They extract a `byte array`.Each derived class manages the generation of this `byte` array in its own way.

Comment: But Node is an abstract class. They can not create an instance of it.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian so basically `Cell` have to expose a byte array?

Comment: The `Api` would handle the lower level which is the `Node` level .They would work with `Cells` but sometimes they would need the `raw` content.And they must have a way in the `Cell` to access it.The `Node`-s are indeed not instantiated by them.Yes the `Cell` has to expose a property which now i think should be a byte array but it can change.Anyway the `Cell` has to expose a variable that is deep inside the `Node`.

Comment: Something like `public byte[] Value => node.GetRaw()`?

Comment: Yes the `Cell` has to expose something like that.But i can not place a `Node` inside the cell because the compiler cries of inconsistent accesibility,since `Node` is `internal` and so are `Node`-s derived classes;whereas `Cell` is public.

Comment: Because is public, declare node private.

Comment: Oh ....i'm dumb..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply make `Node` public and keep its derived classes internal. Unrelated to that, you should think about not deriving `Node` in nested classes for better maintainability:

```
public abstract class Node {
}

internal class ANode : Node {
    public byte[] internalValue;
}

internal class BNode : Node {
    public int internalValue;
}
```

If you want to be able to create instances of `ANode` and `BNode` from external assemblies, you can use an abstract factory:

```
public static class NodeFactory {
    public Node CreateNode(byte[] value) {
        return new ANode { internalValue = value };
    }

    public Node CreateNode(int value) {
        return new BNode { internalValue = value };
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought you can't have the containing class `public` and the nested ones `internal`.I thought all the hierarchy must share the accessor.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: No it doesn't and a lot of design patterns rely on that fact. You can't change *member* accessibility, but you can change *type* accessibility.